# Swift headless webView

Tags: swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am trying to create an app that uploads data to a third party website via a form on their site. I don’t have access to the backend of the website, so my process so far to test has been loading the site in a WKWebView and using evaluateJavascript to place my data into the input fields, then ‘clicking’ submit.

This works, but I’d like it to happen in the background (i.e. no visible webView on the screen).

I’ve seen third party packages like Erik and WKZombie offer headless browsing but I’m wondering if there is a way to do it without these?

[This page](https://nemecek.be/blog/19/using-wkwebview-in-headless-mode) talks about setting the frame to .zero but crashes the app.

Are there any suggestions for running a headless webview in Swift? If I do need to use a third party package, does anyone have experience to suggest if the app may be rejected?

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds hacky. Does setting `webView.alpha = 0` work?

Comment: https://dev.to/nemecek_f/using-wkwebview-in-headless-mode-3leo

Comment: @jnpdx that looks like the same post that OP linked, but on a different site

Comment: @aheze Good catch

Comment: @aheze I’ll give that a go, problem is I have a table view that I’d like to update as the webview stuff happens (reflecting that each data point has been uploaded) but that won’t happen if there is another view on top. I’ll have a look